# Number of matrices with four symbols with distinct rows and columns

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics

How many square matrices of order four over the set of four distinct elements can be obtained, such that each row and column of the matrices are distinct?
Is it 24? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$24$ would be the number of such matrices where all $4$ elements are distinct, because then you have $4$ options for the top left element, after which you have $3$ for the top right, $2$ for the bottom left, leaving $1$ for the bottom right.

However, you can actually have repeating elements in the matrix, because the only restriction is that all rows and columns are different from each other, and that allows something like:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  a&a\\
  b&c
\end{array}
\right] $$

So, there are more than $24$

OK, so how many are there?

HINT 1:

> You cannot use the same element for all $4$ slots, because then all rows and columns would be the same. And, using an element $3$ times would also not work, for then there has to be at least one column with that element for both of its slots, and there will also be such a row, and so that row and column would be the same. So, you can use an element at most twice. Now, can you use two elements both twice? Some quick thinking reveals that that cannot work either: you will definitely get two of the same rows, or two of the same columns, or a row and a column that are the same. So, the matrices you are missing other than the $24$ are the ones like I showed: with one elements occurring twice, and two other elements each occurring once.  So, you need to figure out how many there are of those.

HINT 2:

> There are $4$ choices to pick the element that occurs twice ... and there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to place those in the matrix. Then, for the 'third' location in the matrix, you need to pick one of $3$ remaining elements, and, then there are $2$ elements left for the last spot. So, there are $4 \cdot 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 144$ of these kinds of matrices. Together with the $24$, that gives a total $168$ matrices of the kind you are looking for.